# How To Decorate URL using .htaccess and Remove .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is Current URL and i want to remove "/public/index.php" from the URL then How to write .htaccess

> Blockquote
>   http://localhost/Fresh/public/index.php

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This is my Directory Structure 
[image]

How to rewrite .htaccess to remove subdirectory and Decorate the URL.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Hope it will help you.